# QShortcut- как обьявить переменную как член класса

Tags: qt, qwidget

Пытаюсь использовать QShortcut, и когда обьявляю его в конструкторе, все компилируется хорошо:

```
   QShortcut  *keyCtrlL;
    keyCtrlL = new QShortcut(this);
    keyCtrlL->setKey(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_L);
    connect(keyCtrlL, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MyPage::logicMenu);
```

Нобоюсь работать праивильно не будет - потому что переменная локальная в кострукторе. Выношу обьявление   `QShortcut  *keyCtrlL;`  в файл заголовка `.h` как переменную класа, и получаю ошибку компиляции:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'QWidget *' with an rvalue of type 'MyPage *'
    ui->setupUi(this);
                ^~~~
./qt/forms/ui_mypage.h:69:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'MyPage' here
    void setupUi(QWidget *MyPage)
                          ^
qt/mypage.cpp:153:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'QShortcut'
    keyCtrlL = new QShortcut(this);
```

Хотя MyPage наследует от класса QWidget. Что значит ошибка и что я делаю не так?

Comment: Первый вариант будет работать нормально, вы объявляете не переменную на стеке, а указатель на объект в куче. А передача `this` в качестве параметра в конструктор гарантирует, что все удалится как надо. А вот со вторым вариантом у вас происходит что-то странное, объявление поля так влиять не должно. Я пока не понимаю, в чем проблема, нужно больше кода.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver спасибо за подробный комментарий, стало понятно почему работает и так. По поводу  переменной класса выяснилось что не сделан #include <QShortcut> в файле заголовка, ошибка которую пишет компилятор дает мало подсказки в чем дело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле заголовка не была включена библиотека

```
#include <QShortcut>
```

Но так же в этом случае в файл заголовка лучше включить вместо include
forward declaration:

```
class <QShortcut>
```

Это так же позволит избежать ошибки компиляции, но время сборки будет быстрее и можно избежать циклических зависимостей.